# Angular client with with cors and phalcon api

Tags: angular, cors, phalcon

I use an Angular client to send a request to a phalcon API that works with CORS. The GET requests working great, but at the POST request, I don't get the body. it's always null.

This is my angular client post request (its a test function, if the api gets the request body too):

```
delete() {
  const tag = 'testclienttag';
  const body = {
    filename: 'test.txt',
    version: '2'
  };

  this.http.post(this.fileServerUrl + 'file/delete/' + tag, body, this.header())
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
}

private header() {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': this.oAuthService.getAccessToken()
    })
  };
  return httpOptions;
}
```

this is the requested payload:

```
{
  filename: "test.txt",
  version: "2"
}
```

and this is the phalcon function which is called through the request:

```
public function deleteAction($tag) {
  $errors = [];
  $data = [];

  $data['tag'] = $tag;
  echo 'tag: '.$data['tag']."\n";
  if ((!is_null($tag)) && (!is_string($tag)))
    $errors['tag'] = 'String expected';

  if ($this - > request - > getPost('filename') != null) {

    $data['file_name'] = $this - > request - > getPost('filename');
    echo 'fileName: '.$data['file_name']."\n";
    if ($data['file_name'] != null) {
      if (!is_string($data['file_name']))
        $errors['file_name'] = 'String expected';
    }

  }

  if ($this - > request - > getPost('version') != null) {

    $data['version'] = $this - > request - > getPost('version');
    echo 'Version: '.$data['version'].
    "\n";
    if ($data['version'] != null) {
      if (!ctype_digit($data['version']) || ($data['version'] < 0))
        $errors['version'] = 'The version must be a positive Integer';
    }
  }...more code here but not relevant
}
```

this is what the api gets:

```
{
  "tag": "testclienttag",
  "filename": null,
  "version": null
}
```

Can someone help me?
thanks in advance

***UPDATE***

solved it:
have to use at the Api side : $rawBody = $this->request->getJsonRawBody(true);

Answer (score 0):

For Development with ng serve, If you are using Angular CLI 6. We can configure proxy.conf which will act as proxy for your Backend API and avoid CORS error.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: is there aa other solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Angular post seems suspicious (the `tag` and `body` vars separated seem to be another parameter in the `http.post` request). Would it be possible to pass the params in an array like:

```
const data = {
    tag: 'testclienttag',
    filename: 'test.txt',
    version: '2'
};
```

and then parse the `data` parameter in `deleteAction`?

Comment: its possible and i tried it. but i try ti get tag, filename and version from body its still null.